# Changing to Night mode duplicates items in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-darkmode

In my app i have a settings activity to change app to **dark mode** with `SwitchPreference` and when there is change in preference app move to `MainActivity` - parent activity and the `MainActivity` recyclerView item are duplicated.

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // same as defined in preference.xml file.
    public static final String TAG = "Debug";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
            SwitchPreference switchPreferenceCompat = findPreference(getString(R.string.key_dark_mode));

            assert switchPreferenceCompat != null;
            switchPreferenceCompat.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
                boolean isChecked = false;
                if (newValue instanceof Boolean)
                    isChecked = (Boolean) newValue;
                if (isChecked) {
                    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.key_dark_mode), true).apply();
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreatePreferences: NIGHT mode on");
                } else {
                    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.key_dark_mode), false).apply();
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreatePreferences: nightmode off");
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how i read in main activity :

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
       
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean switchPref = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.key_dark_mode), false);
        //Toast.makeText(this, Boolean.toString(switchPref), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (switchPref) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            //setTheme(R.style.NightMode);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            //setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I even tried `MainActivity` without **PreferenceManager** still items in recyclerView are duplicated.

Comment: Pl try clearing the ArrayList/list you are using to populate the recycler view before adding elements. Or share your activity code where you are populating your ArrayList and initializing your adapter.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela when i change darkmode in `settings activity` the app is restarted means it goes to `splash screen` it starts from first activity. is this how it works or is there any way without doing this